# How I Can Find The Possible Combinations That Form The Given Input

Tags: groovy, jvm-languages

I have a list like this, say for example the list name is `output` which has:

```
[[[o, g], [g, o]], [[o, g, o, d]], [[o, d]], [[t, s, n, e, e, e, n, c, s]], [[t, s, n, e, e]], [[e, n, c, s]]]
```

And I have a input like this, say `input` is:

```
ogodtsneeencs
```

Now obviously, the `input` can be formed from `output`. I tried the `subsequences()` of `output` to find the possible combinations that form the `input`, but the thing is it wont work for all the `input`.

Can anyone say me how I can find the combinations of `output` that will be equal to `input`? And possibly store in some `list`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say `obviously`, but the question isn't really that obvious :-(

Comment: So we can't find ? :( want to delete my question?

Comment: It's not that we can't find...it's that I don't know what you're asking.  You want to re-generate `ogodtsneeencs` from that list?  Or you want to just generate something else?

Comment: yes exactly i want to regenerate the `ogodtsneeencs` from the list.. However there are many ways of regenerating it using `output`. I want all those ways. Am I clear now?

Comment: @tim_yates: well, I thought `subsequences()` will work. But the thing is it is working in only some case. Not in all case's...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given just this small set of test data you have supplied, I came up with this:

```
def list = [[['o', 'g'], ['g', 'o']], [['o', 'g', 'o', 'd']], [['o', 'd']], [['t', 's', 'n', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'c', 's']], [['t', 's', 'n', 'e', 'e']], [['e', 'n', 'c', 's']]]

// For every combination of the lists
def result = list.combinations().collect { combination ->
  // Join them into strings
  combination*.join().with { stringcombo ->
    // Then find every string in the list
    stringcombo.findAll { word ->
      // Which is not a substring of another string in the list
      (stringcombo - word).every { it.indexOf( word ) == -1 }
    }
  }.permutations()*.join() // Then get every String permutation of these remaining strings
}.flatten().unique() // and get them into a single unique list

// And print them out
result.each {
  println it
}
```

Which prints out:

```
ogodtsneeencs
tsneeencsogod
```

Without more data, it's hard to tell if it is correct, but it might be a good starting place for you

#### edit

Updated to return all permutations of the valid tokens

Comment: @Ant's Updated to return all permutations of the valid tokens